# Fetch element child elements in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I need to fetch the element child node using XQuery (i am using eXist-db).

```
<component> 
  <section classCode="DOCSECT" moodCode="EVN"> 
    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.4"/>  
    <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.441.1.50.300011.51.26840.61" extension="a20f6b4c8538492d"/>  
    <code code="10164-2" displayName="HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>  
    <title>History of Present Illness</title>  
    <text mediaType="text/x-hl7-text+xml"> 
      <table border="1"> 
        <thead> 
          <tr> 
            <th>Diagnosis</th>  
            <th>Date</th> 
          </tr> 
        </thead>  
        <tbody> 
          <tr> 
            <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_diagnosis_1">Abscess Of Breast Associated With Childbirth</td>  
            <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_date_1">03/20/2013</td> 
          </tr>  
          <tr> 
            <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_diagnosis_5">Fibrocystic Mastopathy</td>  
            <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_date_5">03/20/2013</td> 
          </tr> 
        </tbody> 
      </table> 
    </text> 
  </section> 
</component>
```

need to fetch the value for `<text>` tag.

```
<table border="1"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th>Diagnosis</th>  
      <th>Date</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead>  
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_diagnosis_1">Abscess Of Breast Associated With Childbirth</td>  
      <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_date_1">03/20/2013</td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr> 
      <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_diagnosis_5">Fibrocystic Mastopathy</td>  
      <td ID="ref_9f2173a9a20b4b7989001f10616bca5e_presentIllness_date_5">03/20/2013</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

If i using the following query, the result start with `<text>` tag. But i need only the html content inside it.

```
return  $section/text
```

I try for `return  $section/text/string()` and `return  $section/d:text/text()` , but it getting mix of `<tr>` and `<td>` values.

Following is not possible because some time `<text>` contain direct values without any html tag.

```
return  $section/text/d:table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"If i using the following query, the result start with  tag. But i need only the html content inside it.*
>
> *`return  $section/text`*"

Instead of `$section/text`, you can return direct child element of `text` like so : **`$section/text/*`**.

> *"Following is not possible because some time `<text>` contain direct values without any html tag `return $section/text/d:table`"*

In this case, replace `*` with `node()`. The latter will match any kind of node i.e either element or text node : **`$section/text/node()`**